# Login with user type in java web

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I need for my college project a login with user type autentication, its already working with email and password but i dont know how can i send the user to a view depending on the type his user.

I use a oracle database that I made, is like this :

```
TypeUser(table one)
-idUser PK
-description

User(table two)
-correo PK
-pass
-TypeUser_IdUser FK
```

i've never do this before so I do not know how to start

```
//the java class 

public class Consultas extends Conexion{

    static Connection conn;


    //Email - Pass
    public boolean autenticacion(String correo, String pass) {
        OraclePreparedStatement pst = null;
        OracleResultSet rs = null;
        conn = Conexion.conexion();

        try {
            String consulta = "select * from usuario where correo = ? and pass = ?";
            pst = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(consulta);
            pst.setString(1, correo);
            pst.setString(2, pass);
            rs = (OracleResultSet) pst.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
            return true;

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error" + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (pst != null) {
                    pst.close();
                }
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error" + e);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }



}
```

```
    //this is the servlet

    String correo = request.getParameter("correo");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    String mensaje="";

    Consultas co = new Consultas();
    if (co.autenticacion(correo, pass)) {
        HttpSession objsesion = request.getSession(true);
        objsesion.setAttribute("correo", correo);

        if (co.autenticacion(correo, pass) || correo.equals ("efrensotex@gmail.com")) {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }else if(correo.equals("empleado.2l@gmail.com")){
            response.sendRedirect("indexEmpleado.jsp");
        }else if(correo.equals("prov@gmail.com")){
            response.sendRedirect("indexProve.jsp");
        }else{
        response.sendRedirect("indexCliente.jsp");
        }
    } else {

        mensaje = "Usuario desconocido";
        request.setAttribute("mensaje", mensaje);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
```

in the servlet i have to put the admin email to send the user to his usertype view. Any help or tutorial I'd be really grateful

PD : I user Netbeans and SqlDeveloper

Comment: Do you have collumn in database for types of users

Comment: yes, 1 - admin, 2 - worker , 3- client

Comment: why not add if statement `if( user.getType() == 1 )...`

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Servlet,

You can fetch idUser  from TypeUser along with correo and pass by executing join query.
Hence you will get user type, After checking credential if its valid you can use switch case for user type, And redirect them as per their types.

```
     if (co.autenticacion(correo, pass){
        int userType = request.getParameter("userType");
        Switch(usertype){
         case 1:
            redirect("1.jsp");
            break;      
        case 2:
            redirect("2.jsp");
            break;      
        }
     }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: its tells me "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: edit : I had to put a drop-down list with user types in the login to work, but the result is what I expected, thank you very much you save me

Comment: seeking your upvote/accepatnce if it could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I was also encountered with with this of situation.So i used the code mentioned below.Hope you find some alternative ways to improve your code.

**processLogin.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page import="com.elibrary.DAO.UserDAO"%>
<%@page import="com.elibrary.beans.UserBean"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Verifying login</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="com.elibrary.beans.UserBean"/>
<c:set property="email_id" target="${user}" value='${param.email_id}'/>
<c:set property="password" target="${user}" value='${param.password}'/>
<%
UserBean userbean=UserDAO.varifyLogin(user);
if(userbean!=null){
    if(userbean.getUser_type_id()==1){
        Cookie cookie=new Cookie("email_id",userbean.getEmail_id());
        cookie.setMaxAge(86400);
        session.setAttribute("admin",userbean);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
        response.sendRedirect("admin/adminhome.jsp");
    }else if(userbean.getUser_type_id()==2){
        Cookie cookie=new Cookie("email_id",userbean.getEmail_id());
        cookie.setMaxAge(86400);
        session.setAttribute("librarian",userbean);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
        response.sendRedirect("librarian/librarianhome.jsp");
    }else if(userbean.getUser_type_id()==3){
        Cookie cookie=new Cookie("email_id",userbean.getEmail_id());
        cookie.setMaxAge(86400);
        session.setAttribute("student",userbean);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
        response.sendRedirect("student/studenthome.jsp");
    }
}else{
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?invalid=1");
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```